# Tras los dos puntos, ¿se escribe mayúscula o minúscula?

Tags: ortografía, puntuación

El signo de los dos puntos (`:`) puede generar un poco de confusión a la hora de saber si, después del mismo, la siguiente palabra se debe escribir con mayúscula o minúscula. Mi idea es que la regla general dice que se escribe minúscula, pero he visto casos en los que no es así.

¿Cuál es la regla exacta al respecto del uso de mayúsculas o minúsculas tras los dos puntos? ¿Qué casos posibles hay? ¿Qué dice la *Ortografía* de la RAE al respecto?